# Cross-evrinment global variable in TypeScript with default value

Tags: typescript, environment-variables

### Problem

Suppose that library includes arbitrarily large number of functions; one function per file:

- doSomethingAlpha.ts
- doSomethingBravo.ts
- doSomethingCharlie.ts
- ...

Some of functions are refers to global `__LANGUAGE_CODE__`:

```
export default function doSomethingAlpha(): void {
  if (__LANGUAGE_CODE__ === "en") {
    console.log("English");
  } else if (__LANGUAGE_CODE__ === "ja") {
    console.log("日本語");
  }
  // ...
}
```

The `__LANGUAGE_CODE__`:

- Must not depend on environment (functions could be used in browser or Node.js, but of course, first it must be compiled to JavaScript and bundled to user's project). It means, we can not use `window`.
- Has default value, but everyone who using this library can change it's value:

```
export { doSomethingAlpha } from "library";

doSomethingAlpha(); // "English"

__LANGUAGE_CODE__ = "ja";

doSomethingAlpha(); // "日本語"
```

Also:

- Library distributes without compiling to JavaScript (it means, we can not use Webpack DEFINE plugin). Library users can bundle the library to their projects by Webpack (or just TypeScript compiler), however library doesn't know about Webpack.
- The library has not some kind of entry point: user takes only function which want to use.

### Musings about solution

We can make TypeScript know about `__LANGUAGE_CODE__` inside library: it's enough to create the `**.d.ts` file and declare:

```
declare const __LANGUAGE_CODE__: string;
```

Unsolved problem is how to define the default value.

```
export { doSomethingAlpha } from "library";

doSomethingAlpha(); // no output because "__LANGUAGE_CODE__" is undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1: Declare the global variable**

```
declare global {
  var __LANGUAGE_CODE__: string;
}
```

Note the use of `var`. This makes `__LANGUAGE_CODE__` available as `globalThis.__LANGUAGE_CODE__`, `window.__LANGUAGE_CODE__` and simply as `__LANGUAGE_CODE__`. It wouldn't work like that with `let` nor `const`.

**Step 2: Define the default**

You need to do it as early in your app as you can.

```
globalThis.__LANGUAGE_CODE__ = 'en';
```

If your library has no single entry point, you can instruct the users of your library to either

- define it themselves, or
- import a module created by you before they use your library. Such a module will mutate their environments when imported.

Example: put your definition in `"library/ennvironment.ts"`.

`environment.ts`

```
globalThis.__LANGUAGE_CODE__ = 'en';
```

User code:

```
import "library/environment";
export { doSomethingAlpha } from "library";

doSomethingAlpha();
```

> Note: every library has *some* kind of entry point. It's defined by
> the `main` field in your `package.json`. If your `main` is simply a
> barrel file (it only re-exports the contents of other modules), you
> can just as well define the default `__LANGUAGE_CODE__` there.

**Step 3: Use it!**

`__LANGUAGE_CODE__` can now be read and redefined using all these methods.

```
globalThis.__LANGUAGE_CODE__;
window.__LANGUAGE_CODE__
__LANGUAGE_CODE__;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! "Import a module created by you before they use your library." - good for my case. I have the single distribution file with functions re-exports (thanks to it, users must not know how files organized). I can initialize `globalThis.__LANGUAGE_CODE__ = 'en';` there as you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `@ngx-translate/core` with files labels

[@ngx-translate/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core)

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example)